# php date() function not functioning when fed with data retrieved from xml

Tags: php

I've a php file in which I've codes like

```
$xml_time = $update->$node->timestamp; **//Case 1**
$time = date("c",$xml_time);

$normal_time = time();    **//Case 2**
$time = date("c",$normal_time );
```

The variable `$xml_time` is retrieved from an external xml file using simpleXML. The time is stored using the `time()` function at some earlier point.

The problem is that, when I call the line `$time = date("c",$xml_time);` (is Case 1), I get an error message saying `<b>Warning</b>:  date() expects parameter 2 to be long, object given in <b>C:\xampp\blah\blah\blah\ajax.php</b> on line <b>46</b><br />` but in Case 2, no error shows up.

Can anyone help me identify the problem??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try if this works:

```
$xml_time = (integer) $update->$node->timestamp; **//Case 1**
$time = date("c",$xml_time);
```

This will typecast SimpleXML object to integer.